# vbscript: how to print multiple files with printer selection dialog once

Tags: vbscript, printing, automation, wmi

I have to write vbscript that prints all files in a folder. **Printer dialog** should popup at the very beginning to allow user to select printer to use. Than all files should be send to printer silently

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I produced something like this (simplified):

```
set objPrnDlg = CreateObject( "MSComDlg.CommonDialog" )
objPrnDlg.PrinterDefault = True
objPrnDlg.ShowPrinter

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(path-to-files) 
set colItems = objFolder.Items 
for each objItem In colItems 
  objItem.InvokeVerbEx ("Print") 
next
```